# React Prompt doesn't work properly in nested Routers

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have TestRouter class which is my parent Router and has routes for 2 components: Test and RouterLinks. RouterLinks is a child Router which has routes for PatternList and PatternCreator components.
In the TestRouter I have defined a Prompt which "when" condition is changed to "true" when you open PatternCreator.

Now I have 2 strange situations.

First one: I go from /patterns to /patterns/patternCreator and when I want to go back using back button of a browser a Prompt pops up (just as intended) but doesn't matter if I click OK or Cancel because it will redirect me to /patterns anyway (before I click OK or Cancel, the URL has already changed).

Second one: I am in /patterns/patternCreator and I am clicking Link to /patterns (this Link is rendered in TestRouter which is present all the time), a Prompt shows up (just as intended) but when I click OK, the URL changes but PatternList is not rendered (I still see PaternCreator). I assume the problem is that the route for TestRouter didn't change so it doesn't see a change and doesn't render different component..?

Any ideas how can I deal with these problems?

Router of TestRouter class:

```
       <Router>
         <Prompt when={this.state.isPromptActivated} message="Are you sure?"></Prompt>

         <LinkTest></LinkTest>

         <Switch>
           <Route path="/patterns" render={(newProps) => <RouterLinks promptActivate={this.promptActivate} promptDeactivate={this.promptDeactivate} apiAuthHeader={this.props.apiAuthHeader} patternValues={this.props.patternValues} {...newProps}></RouterLinks>}>
           </Route>
           <Route path="/test" render={(newProps) => <TestComponent apiAuthHeader={this.props.apiAuthHeader} {...newProps} />}>
           </Route>
         </Switch>

       </Router>
```

Router of RouterLinks class:

```
      <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/patterns" render={(newProps) => <PatternList apiAuthHeader={this.props.apiAuthHeader} {...newProps}/>}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/patterns/patternCreator" render={(newProps) => <PatternCreator promptActivate={this.props.promptActivate} promptDeactivate={this.props.promptDeactivate} apiAuthHeader={this.props.apiAuthHeader} {...newProps}/>}>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it. To make it work I just needed to remove `<Router>` tags in the nested Router.

Comment: Removing <Router> tags can only cause other bugs.